# How to add Open Graph Tags in Custom Module detail page?

Tags: 8

For Node I already used https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

For my custom module's detail page would like to add Open Graph tags for FB share.

So in **my_test.module**

```
function template_preprocess_my_detail_page(&$variables) {

  $items = $variables['item'];

  $title =  $items->title;

  $og_title = [
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => [
          'property' => 'og:title',
          'content' => $title,
        ],
      ];

  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$og_title, 'og_title'];
}
```

Above one suppose to work but **NOT WORKING**.

```
function MY_MODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {

  $og_title = [
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => [
          'property' => 'og:title',
          'content' => '',
        ],
      ];


  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$og_title, 'og_title'];
}
```

Above one is working, But I'm not able to get Page Variables. How will I get `$variables` in above function?

This one called in all pages of module, but I want to call only on detail page as mentioned in `proprocess` function

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need this.

```
    /**
 * Alter the metatags for pages that are not of content entities.
 *
 * @param array $metatags
 *   The special metatags to be added to the page.
 * @param array $context
 *   The context, containing the entity used for token replacements.
 */
function hook_metatags_alter(array &$metatags, array $context) {
  // Exclude metatags on frontpage.
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
    $metatags = NULL;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to get current post details as well. Can i get that then on basis of that need to set meta tags

Comment: Julia what kind of page do you have?

Comment: We are getting data from API & on basis of URL Say `<domain.com>/test/111` will get Id & get data from API

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

So in **my_test.module**

```
function template_preprocess_my_detail_page(&$variables) {

  $items = $variables['item'];

  $title =  $items->title;

  $og_title = [
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => [
          'property' => 'og:title',
          'content' => $title,
        ],
      ];

  $variables['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$og_title, 'og_title'];
}
```

Change from

```
$variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$og_title, 'og_title'];
```

to

```
$variables['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$og_title, 'og_title'];
```